# angularjs variable not update in controller

Tags: angularjs

I need to use this variable in several parts of the control, but to popular with database data nothing happens, the variable is still empty.

```
var _user = null
configApp.dados().query(function (data) {
  _user = data;
  console.log('test:', _vuser) //ok load      
})
console.log('test:', _vuser) //empty
```

**UPDATE**

```
var _user = null
configApp.dados().query(function (data) {
  _user = data;
  console.log('test:', _user) //ok load      
})
console.log('test:', _user) //empty
```

Comment: console.log('test:', _user) Should be _user not _vuser

Comment: only typing error, the problem continues

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about _user variable.
So, if you console.log _vuser variable, it should be empty because you have never declared the variable. I think you are looking for the _user instead since that is the one that gets data from the query.
Thus, the console.log should be something like this:

> console.log('test:', _user)

**UPDATE**

If I understand correctly, you should do something like this:

```
var _user = null
configApp.dados().query(function (data) {
  _user = data;
  console.log('test:', _user) //ok load    
  // continue your controller code that you want to use this _user data form here  
})
//console.log('test:', _user) //empty
```

This happens because it executes the second console.log before the first one that actually gets the data because it has been waited for the query to respond.

Comment: Exactly this, but it still does not load the data

Comment: The issue must be in either configApp.dados() or .query() part. You should debug it to know where exactly is causing the problem.

Comment: On the first console it returns the data correctly in the _user variable, even if I put it in the view works perfectly. What you want is to use this variable with a new value in the rest of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

In any javascript, **the code executes top to bottom**.

So, in your case, the **first `console.log`** is inside a query function, so **it will be called only when you get the response from `api`**.

The **second `console.log`**  is called even before the `api` gives result as the code continues execution from top to bottom.

To be more specific please change the `console.log` to below:

```
var _user = null
configApp.dados().query(function (data) {
  _user = data;
  console.log('test:', _user) //ok load
  console.log('loaded second after you got data') //ok load
})
console.log('loaded first before you get data') //ok load
console.log('test:', _user) //empty
```

From the above code the result should be:

```
1) loaded first before you get data
2) test:, undefined/null
3) 'test:', _user data
4) loaded second after you got data
```

**Solution:**

Inorder to use that variable every where in your controller, as you tagged `angularjs`, you can use `$scope.user` instead of `_user`

The code will be:

```
 $scope.user = null
    configApp.dados().query(function (data) {
       $scope.user = data;
      console.log('test:',  $scope.user) //ok load
 })
```

Comment: @alebarros, checked my answer?